# Post a JSON with only one line of text

Tags: json

I want to post a json with one line of text ex. `"Hello, I'm waiting for you"`

I tried this: `{ "":"Hello, I'm waiting for you" }`

But doesn't work.

I tried to post only the text, but that doesn't work.
And I tried  `{ "Hello, I'm waiting for you" }` as well, but as I suspected it is a malformed JSON.

**EDITED:**
The goal is to send this HTTP REQUEST

```
POST /controller/action HTTP/1.0
Host: sample.net
Authorization: Basic falseSignOfPasswordAndUser
Content-Type: application/json
"Hello, I'm waiting for your"
```

Comment: What do you mean "post a json"? Where, what for? And yes indeed your example is not syntactically valid.

Comment: I can't expose the whole problem, because privacy contract. But I will edite to explain the best the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As petesiss said you could said an array, but that seems overkill. I would advise you to revise your protocol, or not use json at all.

EDIT: to sum up the discussion in the comments : OP didn't need to send JSON, the protocol only specified he would receive a answer to his request in JSON.
So he sent plain text, it worked and unicorns started walking the earth again (or nearly).

Comment: Sure, I would revise the protocol, but I can't is not mine it's belongs someone else

Comment: Are you implying that the protocol requires you to send some invalid JSON? I don't believe it.

Comment: Is very strange, but I tried all ways before commented, and rejected all except { "":"Hello, I'm waiting for you" }, but I expected a JSON Object, that should have MESSAGE property with "Hello, I'm waiting for you", but return the whole object. Yes are some bad designed in this procotol, how I can send this invalid Post sniff sniff

Comment: Not, I'm explained very bad. The protocol requires I send the mentioned HTTP Request. And Must respond with an JSON Object, with property Message that has the value equal to the phrase I send

Comment: And what does it answer you when you send a valid JSON object?

Comment: The whole JSON object inside the Message Property. I achieve it by plain text!! Some wrong in my first test, please, edit your response to say "Try send plain text and hope the protocol will acept it" and I will marked you as responsed, because you are helping, And you should receive the reputation.

Comment: So you dont want to post json then. Best to find out what format is required before try to code for it...

Comment: The format to post, as Protocol indicates is JSON, but if lets me send a simple line of text, Is not my foult, I can't do anything to change it, is not my procotol

Answer (score 0):

You're a little light on the details, but if for example you want to use `json_decode` in php with the posted value, you ought to be able to post `["Hello, I'm waiting for you"]`

And end up with a single element php array.

```
$x = json_decode('["Hello, I am waiting for you"]');
var_dump($x);
```

results in:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "Hello, I am waiting for you" }
```

Comment: I added more info, can you check it, please?